# Find all sequences of letters and merge, leave the six numbers alone

Tags: regex

So I encountered a problem dataset, it contains a variable sequence of letters, followed by a sequence of six numbers.

#### Input Datastream

```
"A", "a", "2.07", "2.35", "39.00", "82.20", "8.8", "3.80", "B", "2.26", "2.25", "40.00", "80.80", "8.1", "1.86", "D", "Et", "2.07", "2.22", "41.00", "83.80", "8.8", "3.87", "F", "2.05", "2.15", "43.00", "82.20", "8.4", "3.11", "Bc", "2.08", "2.12", "48.00", "82.60", "8.3", "2.47", "Gf", "H", "I", "2.08", "2.10", "46.00", "82.20", "8.1", "2.90", "J", "K", "1.95", "2.08", "38.00", "83.40", "8.7", "1.63", "L", "M", "1.89", "2.07", "45.00", "83.80", "9.0", "1.84", "N", "2.06", "2.05", "41.00", "80.60", "9.0", "4.09", "O", "P", "1.86", "2.04", "48.00", "81.60", "8.6", "2.60", "Qst", "R", "1.95", "2.03", "44.00", "82.80", "8.8", "1.40", "S", "2.03", "2.02", "40.00", "81.40", "8.2", "1.74", "T", "1.95", "2.01", "43.00", "81.80", "9.0", "2.30", "Unh", "1.96", "2.00", "44.00", "82.60", "9.2", "2.40", "V", "W", "C", "1.98", "1.97", "40.00", "82.00", "8.1", "1.15", "Yu", "1.90", "1.96", "41.00", "82.80", "9.6", "2.08", "Z", "a", "bi", "1.90", "1.95", "42.00", "84.20", "9.6", "1.69"
```

#### Question:

I want to merge each of the letter groupings, in the text data set, I have encountered problems creating the correct regex expression to strip out the **", "** between the letters. My thought was to focus on the **",** between the letters and replace them with blanks, thus get the letters to merge.

```
((?:[A-Za-z]*)(", ")(?:[A-Za-z]*))*
```

The intent with the above was to create a named middle capture, ignore the outer and replace the middle capture with empty. What am I missing? All help will be graciously received and be much appreciated.

### Expected Result:

```
"Aa", "2.07", "2.35", "39.00", "82.20", "8.8", "3.80", "B", "2.26", "2.25", "40.00", "80.80", "8.1", "1.86", "DEt", "2.07", "2.22", "41.00", "83.80", "8.8", "3.87", "F", "2.05", "2.15", "43.00", "82.20", "8.4", "3.11", "Bc", "2.08", "2.12", "48.00", "82.60", "8.3", "2.47", "GfHI", "2.08", "2.10", "46.00", "82.20", "8.1", "2.90", "JK", "1.95", "2.08", "38.00", "83.40", "8.7", "1.63", "LM", "1.89", "2.07", "45.00", "83.80", "9.0", "1.84", "N", "2.06", "2.05", "41.00", "80.60", "9.0", "4.09", "OP", "1.86", "2.04", "48.00", "81.60", "8.6", "2.60", "QstR", "1.95", "2.03", "44.00", "82.80", "8.8", "1.40", "S", "2.03", "2.02", "40.00", "81.40", "8.2", "1.74", "T", "1.95", "2.01", "43.00", "81.80", "9.0", "2.30", "Unh", "1.96", "2.00", "44.00", "82.60", "9.2", "2.40", "VWC", "1.98", "1.97", "40.00", "82.00", "8.1", "1.15", "Yu", "1.90", "1.96", "41.00", "82.80", "9.6", "2.08", "Zabi", "1.90", "1.95", "42.00", "84.20", "9.6", "1.69"
```

### Simplified view (with line breaks)

#### Initial Dataset

```
"A", "a", "2.07", "2.35", "39.00", "82.20", "8.8", "3.80", 
"B", "2.26", "2.25", "40.00", "80.80", "8.1", "1.86", 
"D", "Et", "2.07", "2.22", "41.00", "83.80", "8.8", "3.87", 
"F", "2.05", "2.15", "43.00", "82.20", "8.4", "3.11", 
"Bc", "2.08", "2.12", "48.00", "82.60", "8.3", "2.47", 
"Gf", "H", "I", "2.08", "2.10", "46.00", "82.20", "8.1", "2.90", 
"J", "K", "1.95", "2.08", "38.00", "83.40", "8.7", "1.63", 
"L", "M", "1.89", "2.07", "45.00", "83.80", "9.0", "1.84",
"N", "2.06", "2.05", "41.00", "80.60", "9.0", "4.09", 
"O", "P", "1.86", "2.04", "48.00", "81.60", "8.6", "2.60",
"Qst", "R", "1.95", "2.03", "44.00", "82.80", "8.8", "1.40", 
"S", "2.03", "2.02", "40.00", "81.40", "8.2", "1.74", 
"T", "1.95", "2.01", "43.00", "81.80", "9.0", "2.30", 
"Unh", "1.96", "2.00", "44.00", "82.60", "9.2", "2.40",
"V", "W", "C", "1.98", "1.97", "40.00", "82.00", "8.1", "1.15", 
"Yu", "1.90", "1.96", "41.00", "82.80", "9.6", "2.08", 
"Z", "a", "bi", "1.90", "1.95", "42.00", "84.20", "9.6", "1.69"
```

#### Expected Result:

```
“Aa”, “2.07", “2.35”, “39.00", “82.20”, “8.8", “3.80”,
“B”, “2.26”, “2.25", “40.00”, “80.80", “8.1”, “1.86",
“DEt”, “2.07", “2.22”, “41.00", “83.80”, “8.8", “3.87”,
“F”, “2.05”, “2.15", “43.00”, “82.20", “8.4”, “3.11"
"Bc", "2.08", "2.12", "48.00", "82.60", "8.3", "2.47", 
"GfHI", "2.08", "2.10", "46.00", "82.20", "8.1", "2.90", 
"JK", "1.95", "2.08", "38.00", "83.40", "8.7", "1.63", 
"LM", "1.89", "2.07", "45.00", "83.80", "9.0", "1.84", 
"N", "2.06", "2.05", "41.00", "80.60", "9.0", "4.09",
"OP", "1.86", "2.04", "48.00", "81.60", "8.6", "2.60",
"QstR", "1.95", "2.03", "44.00", "82.80", "8.8", "1.40",
"S", "2.03", "2.02", "40.00", "81.40", "8.2", "1.74",
"T", "1.95", "2.01", "43.00", "81.80", "9.0", "2.30",
"Unh", "1.96", "2.00", "44.00", "82.60", "9.2", "2.40",
"VWC", "1.98", "1.97", "40.00", "82.00", "8.1", "1.15",
"Yu", "1.90", "1.96", "41.00", "82.80", "9.6", "2.08",
"Zabi", "1.90", "1.95", "42.00", "84.20", "9.6", "1.69"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can look for:

```
(?<!\d)", "(?!\d)
```

And replace with nothing. Check here [online](https://regex101.com/r/Kgw3QQ/1).

---

- `(?<!\d)` - Negative lookbehind to prevent a digit.
- `", "` - A literal combination of quotes, comma and space.
- `(?!\d)` - Negative lookahead to prevent a digit.

Comment: that is a beautiful solution thank you. I had not thought of that approach.

Answer (score 2):

You want `(?![A-Z])(", ")(?=[A-Z])` with the `g`, `m`, and `i` flags.

```js
const regex = /(?![A-Z])(", ")(?=[A-Z])/gmi;
const input = `"A", "a", "2.07", "2.35", "39.00", "82.20", "8.8", "3.80", 
"B", "2.26", "2.25", "40.00", "80.80", "8.1", "1.86", 
"D", "Et", "2.07", "2.22", "41.00", "83.80", "8.8", "3.87", 
"F", "2.05", "2.15", "43.00", "82.20", "8.4", "3.11", 
"Bc", "2.08", "2.12", "48.00", "82.60", "8.3", "2.47", 
"Gf", "H", "I", "2.08", "2.10", "46.00", "82.20", "8.1", "2.90", 
"J", "K", "1.95", "2.08", "38.00", "83.40", "8.7", "1.63", 
"L", "M", "1.89", "2.07", "45.00", "83.80", "9.0", "1.84",
"N", "2.06", "2.05", "41.00", "80.60", "9.0", "4.09", 
"O", "P", "1.86", "2.04", "48.00", "81.60", "8.6", "2.60",
"Qst", "R", "1.95", "2.03", "44.00", "82.80", "8.8", "1.40", 
"S", "2.03", "2.02", "40.00", "81.40", "8.2", "1.74", 
"T", "1.95", "2.01", "43.00", "81.80", "9.0", "2.30", 
"Unh", "1.96", "2.00", "44.00", "82.60", "9.2", "2.40",
"V", "W", "C", "1.98", "1.97", "40.00", "82.00", "8.1", "1.15", 
"Yu", "1.90", "1.96", "41.00", "82.80", "9.6", "2.08", 
"Z", "a", "bi", "1.90", "1.95", "42.00", "84.20", "9.6", "1.69"`;
const output = input.replace(regex, '');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you! Good karma flying your way.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
("[A-Za-z]*)(", ")([A-Za-z]*")
```

Replace with

```
\1\3
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Hglkqm/1).

Note: if you have more than 2 groups to join, just run the search and replace several times - until no replacement is made.